# Estimating $\left(\Gamma\left(\frac{\alpha}{\sqrt n}\right)\right)^n$ for fixed $\alpha >0$ as a function of (large) $n$

Tags: asymptotics, gamma-function

I am interested in the growth of 
$$f_\alpha(n)=\left(\Gamma\left(1+\frac{\alpha}{\sqrt{n}}\right)\right)^n,$$ 
for positive $\alpha$ and large $n$.
(Preferably something more precise than $1! \leq f_\alpha(n)\leq 2!^n$.)

Using $\Gamma(1+x)=x\Gamma(x)$ we may instead analyse the growth of
$$
\left(\Gamma\left(\frac{\alpha}{\sqrt n}\right)\right)^n
$$
for positive $\alpha$ and $n\to \infty$. 
Any references are welcome!

Comment: Can the asymptotic expansion of $\Gamma$ near zero given here (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function#General) be of some help ?

Comment: Parhaps, I cannot yet say. Thank you for the link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See Magnus-Oberhettinger-Soni p. 11

[image]

and use

$\Gamma(z+1)^n=e^{n\ln(\Gamma(z+1))}$

then you get the asymptotic expansion in terms of $n\rightarrow\infty$

Comment: too complicated ? when $\epsilon \to 0^+$ : $\Gamma(\epsilon) \sim \displaystyle\frac{1}{\epsilon}$ (from $\Gamma(1) = 1$ and $ z\Gamma(z) = \Gamma(z+1)$) hence when $n \to \infty$ :$$\left(\Gamma\left(\frac{\alpha}{\sqrt n}\right)\right)^n \sim \left(\frac{\sqrt{n}}{\alpha}\right)^n = \frac{e^{\textstyle \frac{n \ln n}{2}}}{\alpha^n}$$